# Accessing multidimensional array in Drupal

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

This is as equally a drupal question as a PHP question, I assume.

I have the following print_r($node) array

```
stdClass Object
(
    [vid] => 4
...
    [field_imgleft] => Array
            (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => defaultimgleft
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => defaultimgleft
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

field_imgleft is a field in the content type of the node. Since there will only be one value, [0] is the max for that array. I'm trying to return the value of [value] to a variable, but I am having no such luck with node-> methods or node[...] and so on.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a built in API function to extract field values from an entity: [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7).

You can use it like so:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_imgleft');

$first_item = array_shift($items);

$value = $first_item['value'];
```

This method is recommended over accessing the array directly as it takes care of the field translation for you...no need to worry about using `'und'` any more.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) so you can tap into the dpm() function as an improved print_r();

```
dpm( $node->field_imgleft['und'][0]['value'] );
```

Comment: As far as I know Drupal questions are stil fine here, as long as the crux of the question is related to programming.